# Why firefox and IE doesn't place images full in a li

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html-lists, quirks-mode

Ik want to place images in a slideshow (two separate sliders) and uses a li for that purpose…
It works fine in Chrome and Safari but has problems in Firefox and IE

In firefox it works fine in quirks mode but doesn't work in standard mode:
See the following example:

quirks mode works fine for Firefox:
http://www.newmen-agency.com/

but doesn't work in standard mode:
http://www.newmen-agency.com/index_doct.html

I has to work in standard mode…
What did I do wrong?

see css code below:

```
/* Photo slider */

#slider1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 57%;
    z-index:100;
}    

#slider2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 82%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 57%;
    z-index:100;
}

#slider1 ul, #slider2 ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slider1 img, #slider2 img {
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a max-width seems to help it (btw, Opera did not like either version of the page):

```
#slider1 img, #slider2 img {
    height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```